# Is this use of generics correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

After getting let down by a simple codeline like

```
char _letter = (char)Session["currentLetter"];
```

failing when the session is reset, I found out I wanted to try something. (`currentLetter` keeps track of position in a user table)

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    public static T ValueOrDefault<T>(HttpSessionStateBase session, string sessionkey, T defaultvalue)
    {
        object item = session[sessionkey];
        if (item != null && item.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return (T)item;
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)defaultvalue;
        }

    }
}
```

Is this very wrong? Or am I doing something right here? (The code works, btw)

Comment: You can make it an Extension method..

Comment: `defaultValue` is already of type `T` - so why the cast in the else clause?

Comment: This was my first try on making a generic method. So I wasn't sure how to do it :)

@CD: An extension method of what? HttpSessionStateBase?

Comment: @Christian: Yes, on HttpSessionStateBase

Comment: Yes that actually makes sense. Nice. I wish I could concatenate all comments and all answers and mark "Correct answer" :D Everything helped :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more comments:

1. Instead of `item.GetType() == typeof(T)`, you may have wanted to use:

   `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(item.GetType())`. 
   This would let you support reading a type derived from `T`.
2. That said, in your specific case, if I understand the scenario correctly, I would have returned the default value only if the condition `item == null` is true.

   In your current code, the caller may get the default value returned if he was asking for the wrong type, which might be confusing for the caller as he has no way of knowing if a value was available or not.

   I would risk an assumption that if a caller is trying to get a value using the wrong type, this is *always* due to a bug (and not for example due to invalid user input), and therefore I would prefer to have an `InvalidCastException` thrown on me, so that the bug can be fixed (instead of the bug being hidden by returning a default value).

Comment: This is true. And makes it even more difficult for me to mark _one_ answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace `item.GetType() == typeof(T)` with `item is T`. This way it supports giving you a value types as the base class of what you want. You might want to consider making your method an extension method too.

> currentLetter keeps track of position in a user table

I think this should not be a session state in the first place. But without knowing more about what you mean by that it's hard be sure.

Comment: There are so many users that I list them in a table one letter at a time. The "Index" method takes an optional "letter" variable. If empty it equals "A". I use the "currentLetter" to not jump back to "A" after doing some action on a single user (editing for example). The "currentLetter" session variable is _set_ only on the Index method.

Comment: @Chris But why is this in the session and not part of the url in some form? (For example as a query parameter). Your current code totally breaks with multiple tabs.

Comment: That's a good question, and falls under the "i didn't think about that"-category...

Answer (score 1):

this seems right to me - but you can remove the cast to T from

```
return (T)defaultvalue;
```

into

```
return defaultvalue;
```

as you defined defaultvalue as T.